# UWP override default brush globally

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to override some default `SolidColorBrush` for my whole app:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight1}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight2}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark1}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorDark2}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I add these specific `SolidColorBrush` to my `ThemeDictionary` in `App.xaml` (I have more resources placed there) it has no effect.
However, when I place this `ThemeDictionary` in the `Application.Resources` of a `Page` with a `ListView` it does have an effect.

What is the problem here, and how can I solve it?

Comment: For adding more resources, you need use `MergedDictionaries` , and have you used it ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Right now my `Application.Resources` contain a `ResourceDictionary` placed in there, there is a `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`, the `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries` and some other resources.

Comment: All resources either defined in the `ResourceDictionary`'s in the `MergedDictionaries` or in the root `ResourceDictionary` and `ThemeDictionary`'s work, since those are custom resources? Because the resources I now added, overwrite a resource that is defined in `generic.xaml` from UWP itself. Does this overwriting only work in the page that actually uses these resources? Or is there a way to overwrite these kind of resources for the app globally?

Comment: Sure, you you place the custom resource in the app.xaml file, it will work for whole app.